# Android seekbar with custom thumb

Tags: android, seekbar

I want to create a seekbar like in this image:

[image: seekbar]

The question is, how to place thumb above the progress line?

This line

```
android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"
```

places the thumb in the center of the line. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can assume the whole bar and the above thumb as one seekbar
what you have to do is just include the blank area above the bar in progress and background image and include the blank area below the thumb in the image for thumb.

Comment: Yes, maybe it is the solution, but in this case areas above the seek line and around the thumb will be clickable. But it's not so important for me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am also face same problem..and find out the following solution,

Solution - Adjust your thumb with layer-list..

Create **custom_thumb.xml** (in your drawable folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
android:width="50dp"
android:height="50dp"
android:top="35dp"
android:bottom="35dp"
android:drawable="@drawable/thumb"/>

</layer-list>
```

Adjust width, height,top,bottom as per your need.

and set thumb using following code

```
android:thumb="@drawable/custom_thumb"
```